# Menu icon doesn't always animate when tapped on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, menu, icons, jquery-animate

On my site, www.helloarchie.blue, I have a menu icon that animates to a cross when the user clicks and back again to close the menu, but it's not always reliable on mobile (tested on iphone5c chrome/safari). Unless the user taps on the precise right spot, it won't animate even though the menu will open and close every time.

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu-toggle'),
    toggled = false;

menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!toggled) {
        this.className += " toggled";
        toggled = true;
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace(/\b\stoggled\b/, "");
        toggled = false;
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="sb-toggle-right button-square menu">
    <nav>
        <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="rawr">
            <span class="sr">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="menu-bar bar1"></span>
            <span class="menu-bar bar2"></span>
            <span class="menu-bar bar3"></span>
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.rawr {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 12px;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.645, 0.650);
}
.sr {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0;
}
.menu-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #222;
    width: 26px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    transition: all 300ms;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bar1 {
    top: 0;
    animation: topbar-back 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-play-state: initial !important;
}
.bar2 { 
    opacity: 1; 
}
.bar3 {
    bottom: 0;
    animation: bottombar-back 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-play-state: initial !important;
}

.menu-bar + .menu-bar {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.toggled .bar1 {
    top: 25%;
    animation: topbar-x 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.toggled .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggled .bar3 {
    bottom: 25%;
    animation: bottombar-x 500ms;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

PS. There are vendor pre-fixes, they just aren't shown here.

Is there an easy way to stop it animating at all on mobile to avoid the issue?

Comment: do you also use vendor prefixes?

Comment: No, what an idiot! Completely slipped my mind, that's probably it.

Comment: things would be so much easier if we would have standards :P

Comment: So, I've added them in and it does work now, but it's still not perfect. Though it will always open the menu when tapped, it doesn't seem to animate unless they hit the exact right spot..

Comment: you should update your question then. also, provide some more information on which device/os which behaviour occurs and what you'd like to change